# Are draw delays, during my turn to draw, displayed to the other user/opponent?

Tags: draw-something

If I delay whilst it is my turn to draw in Draw Something, is the delay transmitted to the other user?

Example - I start drawing, but I am then away from my device for 5 minutes to put the kettle on. I then complete my masterpiece when I return. In this scenario, would the other user (opponent?) have a 5 minute delay when watching me draw? Or is this delay "cut" from the game?

Comment: Pretty sure the other person doesn't see the break.

Comment: I am testing this with a friend right now.  Waiting on the results.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After just testing this, **there did not seem to be any noticeable delay**.  This was after I drew something, waited 5 minutes, then finished the drawing, and then submitted it.   Once my friend received the turn, he saw the picture being drawn without any delay.

The delay seems to be either cut from the game or sped up tremendously.

Comment: Though in my experience, it does send delays _while drawing_ - that is, if you draw a line quickly, the other person sees it being drawn quickly; if you draw a line slowly, the other person sees the line being drawn slowly. I think it's only transmitting a digest of touch events.

Comment: Note that it does seem to pause during extended sequences of undos (although it doesn't show the undo'ed actions). I think.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I want a delay, such as when I've finished the bulk of the drawing but want to practice shading and other enhancements without wasting my partners time watching me. I'll choose the eraser tool and slowly draw lines and tap  white was several time. It than looks like I've stopped drawing to the other person and they can lay down that final letter to complete the  word ( it's polite to watch the other person's whole drawing)